# Zabbix-server-mysql on docker centos:latest skips some files during install

Tags: yum, docker, zabbix

I tried to install Zabbix-server-mysql on genuine centos image in docker container:

```
[root@desktop]# docker run --rm -ti centos:latest /bin/bash
[root@0e4f336ff674]# rpm -Uvh http://www.elrepo.org/elrepo-release-7.0-2.el7.elrepo.noarch.rpm
[root@0e4f336ff674]# rpm -ivh http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/x86_64/e/epel-release-7-9.noarch.rpm
[root@0e4f336ff674]# yum install http://repo.zabbix.com/zabbix/3.2/rhel/7/x86_64/zabbix-server-mysql-3.2.3-1.el7.x86_64.rpm
```

This manual:
https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.2/manual/installation/install_from_packages/server_installation_with_mysql requires a file "/usr/share/doc/zabbix-server-mysql-3.2.3/create.sql.gz" to be created during the installation due to its necessity to create zabbix DB on MySQL server. But this file appears missing:

```
[root@0e4f336ff674]# ls -ld /usr/share/doc/zabbix-server-mysql-3.2.3/create.sql.gz
ls: cannot access /usr/share/doc/zabbix-server-mysql-3.2.3/create.sql.gz: No such file or directory
```

The funny part is this file actually EXISTS in *.rpm file:

```
[root@0e4f336ff674]# rpm2cpio http://repo.zabbix.com/zabbix/3.2/rhel/7/x86_64/zabbix-server-mysql-3.2.3-1.el7.x86_64.rpm | cpio -t | grep create
./usr/share/doc/zabbix-server-mysql-3.2.3/create.sql.gz
```

Moreover, the package doesn't seem to have any pre- or post-install scripts that could delete the `/usr/share/doc/zabbix-server-mysql-3.2.3/` directory:

```
[root@0e4f336ff674]# rpm -qp --scripts http://repo.zabbix.com/zabbix/3.2/rhel/7/x86_64/zabbix-server-mysql-3.2.3-1.el7.x86_64.rpm
preinstall scriptlet (using /bin/sh):
getent group zabbix > /dev/null || groupadd -r zabbix
getent passwd zabbix > /dev/null || \
    useradd -r -g zabbix -d /var/lib/zabbix -s /sbin/nologin \
    -c "Zabbix Monitoring System" zabbix
:
postinstall scriptlet (using /bin/sh):

if [ $1 -eq 1 ] ; then 
        # Initial installation 
        /usr/bin/systemctl preset zabbix-server.service >/dev/null 2>&1 || : 
fi 
/usr/sbin/update-alternatives --install /usr/sbin/zabbix_server \
    zabbix-server /usr/sbin/zabbix_server_mysql 10
:
<...>
```

So what could be the problem with it?

P.S.: I am aware of the exising official zabbix-on-docker images: github.com/zabbix/zabbix-docker

Answer (score 0):

May be it blocks on "systemctl preset" because in a systemd-controlled operating system that one tries to talk to the systemd daemon to execute the command. However in a docker container there is no systemd daemon.

You could try to avoid that potential problem by using the https://github.com/gdraheim/docker-systemctl-replacement to execute the "systemctl preset".

Comment: I doubt that this is the problem since `centos:latest` has `/usr/bin/systemctl` already built in:  
`[root@desktop]# docker run -ti --rm centos:latest /bin/bash`  
`[root@79cfd0768438 /]# ls -la /usr/bin/systemctl`  
`-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 645888 Mar  7 13:27 /usr/bin/systemctl`  

Moreover, the `%any_command% || :` will always return `TRUE` because of `|| :`, even if file doesn't exist:  
`[root@79cfd0768438 /]# /NoSuchCommand || :`  
`bash: /NoSuchCommand: No such file or directory`  
`[root@79cfd0768438 /]# echo $?`  
`0`

Answer (score 0):

According to https://github.com/tianon/docker-brew-ubuntu-core/issues/122, you should add this to the top of the `Dockerfile`:

```
# Do not exclude man pages & other documentation
RUN rm /etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg.d/excludes
```

Comment: That’s *very* unlikely to help on a CentOS-based image.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't figure out a way to get the `create.sql.gz` file to install while running inside a Docker CentOS 7 container (even though I can start it with systemd running properly), but I did the following workaround:

```
wget https://sourceforge.net/projects/zabbix/files/ZABBIX%20Latest%20Stable/4.2.6/zabbix-4.2.6.tar.gz/download
mv download download.tar.gz
tar -xzvf download.tar.gz
cd zabbix-4.2.6/database/mysql
mysql -uzabbix -p[password] zabbix < schema.sql
mysql -uzabbix -p[password] zabbix < images.sql
mysql -uzabbix -p[password] zabbix < data.sql
```

And then I could finish the frontend installation of Zabbix.

Annoying, but it worked and was the only way I could get this going without being able to source a `create.sql.gz` file from anywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

The Yum configuration file `/etc/yum.conf` of the CentOS Docker image contains `tsflags=nodocs` which stops the documentation from installing.

The Zabbix `create.sql.gz` file is installed as part of the documentation and this is the reason why it's missing.

To install the `create.sql.gz` file either comment out the `tsflags` line in the `/etc/yum.conf` file or amend it removing no `nodocs` before installing Zabbix.